# Does Organic Groups Views allows post to group relationships?

Tags: 7, views, organic-groups, entities

Does anyone know how to create relationships between Post entity and Group entity. I have a view that lists group posts and I want to add group title on the same row. This issue (http://drupal.org/node/1006860) says it is possible, but it is probably not. But strange, since it is views integration basics.

Answer (score 2):

it's possible, see the screenshot: (open image in new window to see full size) [image: screenshot]. Add the 2 relationships as "required" to only show nodes belonging to groups. 
The naming conventions of the group objects is very confusing to me, it helped me to look at the "og" and "og_membership" tables in the DB and then check the SQL that views builds for you.

Comment: I will try this. But how is that this issue is still active? http://drupal.org/node/1238186